# Creating recursive discriminated unions values

Tags: recursion, f#, discriminated-union

When I have this code:

```
type HtmlNode = 
    | HtmlElement of name:string * attribute:HtmlAttribute list
    | HtmlText of content:string

and HtmlAttribute =  
    | HtmlAttribute of name:string * value:string * parent:HtmlNode

let createElement name attrs =
    let toAttributes element = [ for name, value in attrs -> HtmlAttribute(name, value, element)]
    let rec element = HtmlElement(name, attributes)
    and attributes = toAttributes element
    element
```

The compiler gives the following error:

> Recursive values cannot appear directly as a construction of the type 'HtmlNode' within a recursive binding. This feature has been removed from the F# language. Consider using a record instead.

Why is that? The let rec is supposed to support the creation of recursive values, and something similar works with records.

Comment: I don't get an error with this.

Comment: Based on the message, this was probably changed in the most recent version 3.1.

Comment: The same error happens in F# 3.0 - so it is slightly older

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why this was changed, but one workaround is to use `seq` instead of `list`.

```
type HtmlNode = 
    | HtmlElement of name:string * attribute:HtmlAttribute seq
    | HtmlText of content:string

and HtmlAttribute =  
    | HtmlAttribute of name:string * value:string * parent:HtmlNode

let createElement name attrs =
    let rec element = HtmlElement(name, attributes)
    and attributes = seq { for name, value in attrs -> HtmlAttribute(name, value, element) }
    element
```

Comment: Interesting, if I do pass a list or array to the seq, it crashes at runtime

Comment: I noticed that too. It seems a level of indirection is required.